# Numerar linhas em DataGridView em C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho um `DataGridView` e um método para preenchê-lo:

```
public DataTable BuscarClientesEmAtividade()
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    OleDbConnection con = ConexaoBanco();
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT codcli, nomecli FROM TBCLI WHERE ematividadecli = true";
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt; 
}
```

A minha duvida é como fazer com que seja inserida na primeira coluna do `DataTable dt` uma numeração para as linhas do `DataGridView`?

Comment: Você quer numerar as linhas de 1 até a quantidade geral? um lembrete se está ACCESS pelo visto e está usando DataAdapter ele é meio lento ...

Answer (score 0):

Meus amigos esta resolvido, adicionei esse trecho de codigo antes do preenchimento do Datatable pelo dataadapter, se for depois nao funciona direito:

```
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn();

        // configurar varios atributos
        column.ColumnName = "Número";
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.AutoIncrement = true;
        column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        column.ReadOnly = true;
```

Ele funciona criando a coluna em seguida atribui valor inteiro com autoincremento de 1 unidade para cada linha quer for adicionada o que sera feita pelo DataAdapter com dados do banco de dados.
Espero que essa questão possa ajudar outras pessoas coma mesma duvida que a minha :).